# Parsing server side response

Tags: android, json

I have Webservice in .net that [responds me](http://schoolapp.encipherinc.com/SchooAppService/SchoolAppsWebService.asmx/GetRulesCategoriesJson)

For parsing this kind of rsponse i have referred [Android Json Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).
 Any help will be appreciated.But still getting JSONException.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It Seems that your Json format is correct but It shouldn't have xml tag in it.Dont use WebMethod. Invoke the method with tag like this

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
      )]
```